# QProgressDialog bar resets to zero when completes

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QProgressDialog which obviously just shows progress and it increments along the way. When it reaches 100%, the progress bar on it resets to zero instead of showing 100% there after.

progress is member variable of the class.

```
QSharedPointer<QProgressDialog> progress;
```

It is used in on_clicked event. Note I am using Sleep() for simulation, I know it doesn't belong there. The problem is when it reaches 100%, the progress bar shows zero progress and I want to stick to 100%.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonConvert_clicked()
{
    int numFiles = 10;
    progress = (QSharedPointer<QProgressDialog>) new QProgressDialog("Copying files...", "Abort Copy", 0, numFiles, this);
    progress->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
    progress->setAutoClose( false );

    for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
        progress->setValue(i);

        if (progress->wasCanceled())
            break;
        //... copy one file

        Sleep(500);
    }
    progress->setValue(numFiles);
}
```

Comment: have you tried to setMaximumValue() and setMinimumValue() before launching your routine ?

Comment: @LeonardoBernardini I think you mean setMaximum() and setMinimum(), yes but they have no effect on this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I had to call:

```
progress->setAutoReset( false );
```